# Printing XPS with Annotations fails

Tags: wpf, annotations, xpsdocument

this works

```
FixedDocumentSeqeunce fixedDocumentSeqeunce = XPSdoc.GetFixedDocumentSeqeunce();    
DocumentPaginator paginator = fixedDocumentSeqeunce.DocumentPaginator;

printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Title");
```

this fails

```
AnnotationDocumentPaginator adp = new AnnotationDocumentPaginator(paginator, service.Store); 
// same paginator as above    
printDialog.PrintDocument(adp, "Title");
```

printDialog.PrintDocument(adp, "Title"); is what is killing it
Somehow it appears to be corrupting the XPSdoc

Store appears to be good - I can get a count of the annotations
It fail even if I create zero annotations
But the print itself does not fail - I get a valid print
A try catch on the above does not catch an error
A few seconds after the print get errors starting with
(I have a handler for unhandled exceptions)

> The specified visual is not an ancestor of the Visual

App crashes and the XPS document is never repainted in the DocumentViewer

I am able to get FlowDocuments with ScrollViewer to print annotation fine
And create the store the same way so I think that code is fine

.NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what is going on in my larger program but I cannot reproduce it on a smaller program right now

Figure it out
In the failed code I was NOT using

```
FixedDocumentSeqeunce fixedDocumentSeqeunce = XPSdoc.GetFixedDocumentSeqeunce();
```

In the printDialog.PrintDocument I was using the EXACT same fixedDocumentSeqeunce the control was bound to.  Print must alter fixedDocumentSeqeunce so it needs a fresh fixedDocumentSeqeunce.

```
<Window x:Class="APSannotate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:ann="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Annotations;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="click" Content="Print"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Sticky" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Command="ann:AnnotationService.CreateTextStickyNoteCommand"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=docViewer}"/>
        <DocumentViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Document="{Binding Path=FixedDocSeq}" Name="docViewer"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Xps;
using System.Windows.Annotations;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;



namespace APSannotate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        AnnotationService _annotService;
        //FileStream _annotStream;
        System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.XmlStreamStore _annotStore;
        System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument xpsDoc;
        //MemoryStream _streamAnnoMem;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            xpsDoc = new System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(@"c:\temp\ann.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public FixedDocumentSequence FixedDocSeq
        {
            get { return xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence(); }
        }

        private void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            bool? result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result != null && result.Value)
            {
                DocumentPaginator documentPaginator = FixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator;
                printDialog.PrintDocument(documentPaginator, "documentPaginator");

                AnnotationService service = AnnotationService.GetService(docViewer);
                AnnotationDocumentPaginator annotationDocumentPaginator = new AnnotationDocumentPaginator(documentPaginator, service.Store);
                printDialog.PrintDocument(annotationDocumentPaginator, "annotationDocumentPaginator");
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartAnnotations();
        }
        private void StartAnnotations()
        {
            // If there is no AnnotationService yet, create one.
            if (_annotService == null)
                // docViewer is a document viewing control named in Window1.xaml.
                _annotService = new AnnotationService(docViewer);

            // If the AnnotationService is currently enabled, disable it.
            if (_annotService.IsEnabled == true)
                _annotService.Disable();

            // Open a stream to the file for storing annotations.
            //_annotStream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\annoStore", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            // Create an AnnotationStore using the file stream.
            //_annotStore = new System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.XmlStreamStore(_annotStream);

            MemoryStream _streamAnnoMem = new MemoryStream();
            _annotStore = new System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.XmlStreamStore(_streamAnnoMem);

            // Enable the AnnotationService using the new store.
            _annotService.Enable(_annotStore);
        }// end:StartAnnotations()
    }
}
```